# Rails 4 Testing custom classes Unitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rubymine

I am trying to create for my test class ( lib/calorie_form.rb )

```
class CalorieForm
  attr_accessor :is_male, :weight, :age, :height, :physical_activity, :trainings_per_week
end
```

I wrote the following test and put it into 
test/unit/calorie_calculator_test.rb

```
require 'test/unit'

class CalorieCalculatorTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_calculations
    calorie_form = CalorieForm.new
    calorie_form.is_male = false
    calorie_form.weight = 55
    calorie_form.height = 169
    calorie_form.physical_activity = 1.4
    calorie_form.trainings_per_week = 4
  end
end
```

This should be ok (this code works fine when i put it into controller method) but when i run test using rubymine i got following error

```
C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest C:/CalorieCalc/test/unit/calorie_calculator_test.rb
Testing started at 1:19 AM ...
Run options: 

# Running tests:

E

Finished tests in 0.005005s, 199.8002 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
CalorieCalculatorTest#test_calculations:
NameError: uninitialized constant CalorieCalculatorTest::CalorieForm
    C:/CalorieCalc/test/unit/calorie_calculator_test.rb:8:in `test_calculations'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

I have this line in my application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

1. What am i doing wrong ?
2. Is there any way to auto generate test file
   for class located in lib/ using RubyMine 6 ?

**UPDATE**

If i write

```
require 'calorie_form'
```

i got

```
C:/CalorieCalc/test/unit/calorie_calculator_test.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- calorie_form (LoadError)
```

Also i could do

```
require_relative '../../lib/calorie_form'
```

or

```
require 'C:\CalorieCalc\lib\calorie_form.rb'
```

but both variants are very ugly.

Why i can't just write require 'calorie_form' ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you add :

```
require 'calorie_form'
```

to the top of your test file, then it should work for you

Comment: C:/CalorieCalc/test/unit/calorie_calculator_test.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- calorie_form (LoadError)

Comment: Also i could do 
require_relative '../../lib/calorie_form' or 
require 'C:\CalorieCalc\lib\calorie_form.rb' but both variants are very ugly.

Comment: try requiring 'test_helper' from the top of the unit test file, create 'test_helper.rb' in the test/ folder if it does not exist, and add a deliberate exception like 'raise "Loaded TestHelper"' as a probe to make sure the file is being read…